# How do I sum across group of columns based on column names in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with two levels of column index that looks like below table.

```
group1  group1   group2    group2
col1    col2     col3      col4
1       3.5      0.5       4.5
3       2.5      2.5       4.5
4       1.5      1.5       4.5
```

I want to add the columns under same group and output should like this. Please suggest if there are any effective Pandas methods to achieve this.

```
group1  group2
4.5     5.0
5.5     7.0
5.5     6.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only `sum` by first level in `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
print (df1)
   group1  group2
0     4.5     5.0
1     5.5     7.0
2     5.5     6.0
```

Use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) original data by first level in `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = df.div(df1, axis=1, level=0)
print (df2)
         group1              group2          
       col1      col2      col3      col4
0  0.222222  0.777778  0.100000  0.900000
1  0.545455  0.454545  0.357143  0.642857
2  0.727273  0.272727  0.250000  0.750000
```

Comment: Thanks! My final objective was to get percentage across the columns in group. For example - first entry should be 1/4.5. Any suggestions to get that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby` method:

```py
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks! My final objective was to get percentage across the columns in group. For example - first entry should be 1/4.5. Any suggestions to get that. I am trying this `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())` which gets the percentage in the column instead of row.

Comment: df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()